# CSS issue with styling the Google custom search box

Tags: css, google-custom-search, zendesk

I'm trying to include the Google custom search on our help center. The functionality is ok, however, the styling is quite wrong.

I am pretty sure that some CSS must be overriding/interfering with the Google styles, but I can't seem to find out which ones (tables I guess).

More specifically:

1. The text entry field is not vertically center-aligned.
2. The search button is not displayed properly.

This is the link to the sandbox I'm working in, the search bar is in the container below the header: https://acrolinx1429009760.zendesk.com/hc

Side note: I only have access to the one main CSS file from Zendesk.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `text entry field` you mean the assistive text within the input field?

Comment: Yes, indeed. Sorry, I should have clarified: I meant _vertically_ centered inside the box.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `box-sizing: content-box;` to `.cse .gsc-search-button input.gsc-search-button-v2, input.gsc-search-button-v2` for the second issue.

If you want to align center the text in the input field (which I do *not* recommend!), add text-align center to that element. I don't recommend this because people are used to text in a search box to be left aligned. Rather, I'd make your search bar smaller.

So in total, add this CSS:

```
.cse .gsc-search-button input.gsc-search-button-v2, input.gsc-search-button-v2 {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
.gsc-search-box-tools .gsc-search-box .gsc-input {text-align: center;}
```

Though, as I said, I'd recommend leaving out that last line and making the input smaller. Something like this:

```
#cse {
    width: 60%; /* make sure you don't use inline width */
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.cse .gsc-search-button input.gsc-search-button-v2, input.gsc-search-button-v2 {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved the issue with the search button. Do you know why this did not work _out of the box_ when I added the code from Google?

Comment: @tvs It did work out of the box, but on your website you changed the box-model layout of all models by adding `box-sizing: border-box`. That is useful for most elements, but in the case of the button that would be annoying because it limits the height. My code resets the `box-sizing` value to its default, namely `content-box`. Read more about the box model [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box_model) and [here](https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/).

Comment: this worked to get rid of the odd ghosting/double-vision effect of the `search.png` image, once I had adjusted `background-position` `padding` and `margin` as well (to cope with me doubling the image size) - but should `-webkit-box-sizing:` be set to `content-box;` like the others?

Answer (score 0):

Try this it must work:

**CSS**

```
.cse .gsc-search-button input.gsc-search-button-v2, 
input.gsc-search-button-v2 {
  width: auto; // CHANGED
  height: 28px; // CHANGED
  padding: 6px 27px;
  min-width: 13px;
  margin-top: -1px; // CHANGED
}

.gsc-input-box 
 {
  border: 1px solid #D9D9D9;
  background: #fff;
  height: 28px; // CHANGED
 }

input.gsc-input 
{
  font-size: 19px;
  text-align: center; // ADDED
  padding: 4px 9px;
  border: 1px solid #D9D9D9;
  width: 99%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Google custom search automatically insert their style sheet. But you can customize it according to your requirement like here I'm removing the extra height which was appearing as an extra space-

```
<style type="text/css">
   .gsc-control-cse
    {
        height:20px;
        !important;     
    }
    .gsc-control-cse-en
    {
        height:20px;
        !important;
    }
</style>
```

......

```
    <div class="customSearch" style="border:0px solid;margin:-15px;width:30%;height:auto;">
    <script>
      (function() {
        .....
      })();
    </script>
    <gcse:search enableAutoComplete="true"></gcse:search>
    </div>
```